# valueChangeListener doesn't fire

Tags: java, vaadin

I would like to set a CheckBox ReadOnly when my new window pop up. 
Here is my code.

```
getForm().getField("foreign").addValueChangeListener(
    new Property.ValueChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void valueChange(Property.ValueChangeEvent event) {
            changeValueForCurrency(event.getProperty().getValue());
        }
    }
);
```

Tried to let it happen by calling the changeValueForCurrency()

```
changeValueForCurrency(getForm().getField("foreign"));
```

Does not work. 
My mate told me something about to fire it, but It doesn't has any methods like firing it.
Also, I tried to set this method below true;

```
setImmediate(true);
```

Still does not work

Comment: Did you change the value of the field `foreign` and check?

Comment: forgot .getValue() method from its end

Comment: What's the type of `getForm().getField("foreign")`? Is it CheckBox? Usually, checkbox value is getting changed when you tick it. It isn't clear what exactly you want to achieve here, but you might want to try `getForm().getField("foreign").setValue(true)`.

Comment: Did you set a Property object as property data source on your checkbox? If so, you should register the ValueChangeListener on the Property object.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do setImmediate() after adding the listener? i had this issue with a table.